# Laravel array_push returns undefined offset error

Tags: php, laravel, array-push

**Code**

```
$loans2ndChart = Loan::select('date_release')
                         ->where('invalid',false)
                         ->where('transaction_year', $transyear)
                         ->get()
                         ->groupBy(function($date) {
                  
                     return Carbon::parse($date->date_release)->format('m'); // grouping by months
              });

    $chart2Array = [];
    $loanChartArr = [];

    foreach ($loans2ndChart as $key => $value) {
        $chart2Array[(int)$key] = count($value);
    }

for($j = 1; $j <= 12; $j++){
    if(!empty($chart2Array[$j])){
      array_push($loanChartArr,array($loanChartArr[$j],$chart2Array[$j]));  
    }else{
      array_push($loanChartArr,array($loanChartArr[$j],0)); 
    }
}

$loanTypeCount = Loan::select(['loan_type AS name', DB::raw('count(loan_type) AS y')])
                         ->groupBy('loan_type')
                         ->orderBy(DB::raw('y'), 'desc')
                         ->where('transaction_year', $transyear)
                         ->where('invalid', false)
                         ->get();                
                    
    $loanTypeCount->map(function($loan)use($loanChartArr) {
        $loan->sliced = true;
        $loan->selected = true;
        $loan->data = $loanChartArr;
        return $loan;
    });
```

[image]

**Output:** `var_dump($chart2Array );`

```
array(5) { [9]=> int(1) [5]=> int(2) [6]=> int(1) [7]=> int(3) [8]=> int(1) }
```

...and when inserted `isset` in array

```
for($j = 1; $j <= 12; $j++){
    if(!empty($chart2Array[$j])){
      array_push($loanChartArr,array(isset($loanChartArr[$j]),$chart2Array[$j]));  
    }else{
      array_push($loanChartArr,array(isset($loanChartArr[$j]),0)); 
    }
}
```

**Output:** `var_dump($loanTypeCount );`

```
string(568) "[{"name":"Salary","y":"6","sliced":true,"selected":true,"data":[[false,0],[false,0],[false,0],[false,0],[false,2],[false,1],[false,3],[false,1],[false,1],[false,0],[false,0],[false,0]]},{"name":"Emergency","y":"1","sliced":true,"selected":true,"data":[[false,0],[false,0],[false,0],[false,0],[false,2],[false,1],[false,3],[false,1],[false,1],[false,0],[false,0],[false,0]]}]"
```

**Desired Output:**

```
string(568) "[{"name":"Salary","y":"6","sliced":true,"selected":true,"data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,2],[6,1],[7,3],[8,1],[9,1],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]},{"name":"Emergency","y":"1","sliced":true,"selected":true,"data":[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,2],[6,1],[7,3],[8,1],[9,1],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]}]"
```

What is the right way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Please let me know what you want to accomplish as well the data inside the loans2ndChart you receive after the query ?

Comment: The key 1 doesn't exist in the array `$loanChartArr`

Comment: But why it works whenever I use this one? for($j = 1; $j <= 12; $j++){
        if(!empty($chart2Array[$j])){
          array_push($loanChartArr,array(isset($loanChartArr[$j]),$chart2Array[$j]));  
        }else{
          array_push($loanChartArr,array(isset($loanChartArr[$j]),0)); 
        }

Comment: The problem is there is no key 1 because the query has no january month in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In the first attempt in the `for` loop `$loanChartArr[$j]` is not defined yet, this is why you're getting undefined offset error

```
$loanChartArr = [];
...

for($j = 1; $j <= 12; $j++){
    if(!empty($chart2Array[$j])){
      array_push($loanChartArr,array($loanChartArr[$j],$chart2Array[$j]));  
    }else{
      array_push($loanChartArr,array($loanChartArr[$j],0)); // <=  $loanChartArr[$j] is not defined yet 
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you add on the code? I did defined it at the top.

Comment: Isset() returns boolean what are you try to do

Comment: What I want to do is to replace that boolean cause by isset by actual number. My desired output is shown above.

Comment: I just wanted to see what the actual format is that is why I use isset function. When I remove that it says undefine offset 1

Comment: @Eli in the first iteration the array is empty

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? I know it is empty that is why I am assigning zero value into it.

Comment: When I define it, then zero will not fall in the fist index then?